# How Can i Call Form1 load event from from Form2 button click event

Tags: c#

I have a two simple windows form:FormA and FormB.
in my FormA has a simple datagridView And i show the my simple table information,i use the this code to show the my information in FormA load event:

```
 string selectcommand = "select *from WhiteList";
            SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
            SqlCeDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlCeDataAdapter(selectcommand, conString);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adaptor.Fill(ds, "test");
            DataTable table = ds.Tables["test"];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

when the information show in datagridView and when user click on gridView Row,Open FormB and show the DatagridView fields in FormB textBox,in FormB i use this code:

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conString);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("Update WhiteList set Name=@behi,Count=@rezi where id=@rezii", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@behi", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rezi", Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rezii", Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to Update the my simple table,But I want when click the Update Button on the FormB,in FormA datagridView refresh,How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling method on one form from another form, fill combobox on Form1 if a button on Form2 is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080235/calling-method-on-one-form-from-another-form-fill-combobox-on-form1-if-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class FirstForm: Form
{
public FirstForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecondForm form2 = new SecondForm (this);
    SecondForm .Show();
}
public void UpdateDataGrid()
{
//add your code here
}



}

public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
private FirstForm form1;

public SecondForm ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public SecondForm (FirstForm form1)
    : this()
{

    this.form1 = form1;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.UpdateDataGrid();
}
}
```